# how to make two lists from a dictionary using lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
d1={'n1':1,'n4':0,'n2':2}
l1=[] 
l1=[lambda x : for x in d1.keys()]
print l1
```

the above code is failing to produce the list.How can i correct it?

Comment: You don't need a lambda l1 = [x for x in d1.keys()]. Maybe that's what you want to do?

Comment: It is to me unclear which **two** list you want to create

Comment: it works for l1 = [x for x in d1.keys()]

Answer (score 1):

Okey, just to answer your question, it will surprise you :P:

```
d1={'n1':1,'n4':0,'n2':2}
l1=[] 
l1=[(lambda x : x)(x) for x in d1.keys()]
print l1
```

and it prints:

```
['n1', 'n2', 'n4']
```

Even confuser?

```
l1=[(lambda x : x)(x) for x in d1.keys()]
```

gives same result... **How to do it best? probably:**

```
l1=[x for x in d1.keys()]
```

**even better?**

> d1.keys()

Comment: you forgot about `map(lambda x: x, d1)`

Comment: @aws_apprentice nice one, should I add it too? just to be even clear :P hahaha, thanks for comment

Comment: and **list(d1.keys())**

Comment: thanks Damian every answer mentioned works...why we needed () in lambda function ...didn't get what really changed when you did l1=[(lambda x : x)(x) for x in d1.keys()]  ..instead of l1=[lambda x : for x in d1.keys()]

Comment: @abhilash because it means call the function ;), is the same if you do def a(): pass . Then if you do a, nothing happens, but if you do a(), it will execute, do you understand? don't forget to mark the answer :) with the check box top left in my answer, thanks you